# Load different website urls in different activities using Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new to Android app development and so far I have been able to develop a prototype that displays one url.  I trued adding another webview which is set to load a different URLs but whenever I open the second activity, the application shuts down. Is it possible to achieve this and if so,  HOW? Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample code in my android application.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_Two"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity__two" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityThree"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_three" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_webview);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://test.biko.me.ke");

    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
}
```

**Activity_Two.java**

```
public class Activity_Two extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.two_webview);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://biko.me.ke");

    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in AndroidManifest.xml file.You have to register 2nd activity in AndroidManifest.xml file. After that you can move to 2nd activity without any crash. Here is an example. First activity is main launcher activity and 2nd is other activity

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.tenmb.androidexpert.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tenmb.androidexpert.Beginners.ButtonExample"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Hi @waheed, I tried your method, but it did not work. I have updated my question to include the code I have. Hope it gives better perspective of my position

Comment: Good,Instead of just using .Activity_Two, use packagename+activity like com.example.Activity_Two.
You can send me code over my email id i will solve that issue. waheed.nu@gmail.com

Comment: I will edit that piece of code and tell you the  results. Though I am not accessing activity two with a button but rather the App's main menu (using the menu button)

Comment: Always try to do work in parts.First open a new activity on a button click then add functions in that activity.Follow same procedure everywhere that will help you a lot.

Comment: Hi @waheed, tried a couple of things but none worked. Which files in particular would u like me to send you?

Comment: Send me complete code if its not important, i hope its a basic project and explain everything where you want particular things.

Comment: Hey,  I found thwe problem...in the Activity-_Two.java file, i had called the wrong layout file that did not have the id two_webview. Cheers and thanks for your input.